# Biztalk Service returns flat file message is not recognized

Tags: azure, biztalk, edi, x12

I have an edi file with which I am attempting to test with.  I am attempting to validate and process an x12 214 v 4010 file.  This is the schema I have loaded into Biztalk and my file validates against this schema when I remove the ISA & GS bits.

However, when I deploy to Azure I get the error

> The flat file message is not recognized. Unrecognized messages are not
>   allowed as per the specified configuration.

I must assume the header is what is throwing it off since validation works.  Here is the header that I am using on the file

```
ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*CWCE           *ZZ*ISARECEIVERID  *040805*0416*U*00401*000000001*0*T*>*
GS*QM*CWCE*GSRECEIVERID*20040805*0416*000000001*X*004010*
[Transaction Set Here]
GE*1*000000001*
IEA*1*000000001*
```

Was using CRLF as the segment terminator as Andrew sugged so switched to utilizing ~ as the segment separator and removing all line feeds.  Again I am able to validate against the instance of the schema without the header but as soon as I add the header and publish the service I still get the unrecognized flat file message error.

Here is the header as changed:

```
ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*CWCE           *ZZ*ISARECEIVERID  *040805*0416*U*00401*000000001*0*T*>~
GS*QM*CWCE*GSRECEIVERID*20040805*0416*000000001*X*004010~
[Transaction Set Here]
GE*1*000000001~
IEA*1*000000001~
```

I have tried all variations of this header and I can't get Biztalk to parse the file.  I also don't seem to be able to get any more information out of Biztalk than that single error message.

Appreciate any and all help in advance

Comment: Spitballing here:  does it not like the segment terminator?  Sometimes it'll show as CR/LF which is two characters which technically breaks EDI syntax rules.  I can't see if it is only a CR or LF, so I don't know if my guess is correct.  Can you replace it with a tilde and "wrap" the data?

Comment: @Andrew I updated.  I was using CRLF and I had an element separator at 106.  I took your advice, moved to a ~ separator, and pulled the data into a single line so there were no CR's or LF's.  Unfortunately I seem to be in the same spot.

I am beginning to believe it is with how Partner Agreements work but I've tried setting up an agreement with the exact info in the ISA header and still the same error.

Comment: Is getting rid of BizTalk an option? :)  You might be on the right path with the Partner Agreements.

Comment: @Andrew Sure, do you have any suggestions on standalone edi translators or ones that work well in the .net ecosystem?

Comment: I've worked with over a dozen in my life.  Feel free to contact me off thread using link in my profile.

Comment: It probably is something to do with your agreement - that would be what I'd be checking for an on prem BizTalk install.  I'm not as familiar with it in Azure though, sorry

Comment: @joshlrogers were you able to figure out your issue?

Comment: @Andrew I found a work around but not a solution.  I can't deploy my own message bridge but I can use Azure's management portal and step through the wizard which works.  I can emulate what it creates and try to deploy the exact same thing and goes back to not being able to identify the message.

Comment: here in this tutorial https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh949826.aspx contains the agreement part, but now the portal doesn't have X12 tab, and no 'transform' setting tab, who set it up successfully?